# Find the number total rows analyzed in a MySQL JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join, query-optimization

I have a `MySQL` query which has a `JOIN` of 12 tables. When I `explain` the query, It showing 394699 rows for one table and 185368 rows for another table. All other tables has 1-3  rows. The total result which I am getting from the query id 472 rows only. But for that, **it is taking more than 1 minute**.

Is there any way to check how many rows has been analyzed to produce such a result? So that, I can find which is the table costs the higher time.

**I am giving the query structure below. As the table structure is too  high, I am not able to provide it here.**

```
SELECT h.nid,h.attached_nid,h.created, s.field_species_value as species, g.field_gender_value as gender, u.field_unique_id_value as unqid, n.title, dob.field_adult_healthy_weight_value as birth_date, dcolor.field_dog_primary_color_value as dogcolor, ccolor.field_primary_color_value as catcolor, sdcolor.field_dog_secondary_color_value as sdogcolor, sccolor.field_secondary_color_value as scatcolor, dpattern.field_dog_pattern_value as dogpattern, cpattern.field_cat_pattern_value as catpattern 
FROM table1 h 
JOIN table2 n ON n.nid = h.nid 
JOIN table3 s ON n.nid = s.entity_id 
JOIN table4 u ON n.nid = u.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table5 g ON n.nid = g.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table6 dob ON n.nid = dob.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table7 AS dcolor ON n.nid = dcolor.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table8 AS ccolor ON n.nid = ccolor.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table9 AS sdcolor ON n.nid = sdcolor.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table10 AS sccolor ON n.nid = sccolor.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table11 AS dpattern ON n.nid = dpattern.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN table12 AS cpattern ON n.nid = cpattern.entity_id 
WHERE h.title = '4208'
AND ((h.created BETWEEN 1483257600 AND 1485935999)) 
AND h.uid!=1 
AND h.uid IN(
    SELECT etid 
    FROM `table` 
    WHERE gid=464 
    AND entity_type='user') 
AND h.attached_nid>0 
ORDER BY CAST(h.created as UNSIGNED) DESC;
```

**Below is the EXPLAIN result which I get**

```
    +------+--------------+---------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type  | table         | type   | possible_keys        | key                 | key_len | ref                  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+------+--------------+---------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|    1 | PRIMARY      | s             | index  | entity_id            | field_species_value | 772     | NULL                 | 394699 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | u             | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | n             | eq_ref | PRIMARY              | PRIMARY             | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | g             | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | dob           | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | dcolor        | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | ccolor        | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | sdcolor       | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | sccolor       | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | dpattern      | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | cpattern      | ref    | entity_id            | entity_id           | 4       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      1 |                                              |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | h             | ref    | attached_nid,nid,uid | nid                 | 5       | pantheon.s.entity_id |      3 | Using index condition; Using where           |
|    1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>   | eq_ref | distinct_key         | distinct_key        | 4       | func                 |      1 | Using where                                  |
|    2 | MATERIALIZED | og_membership | ref    | entity,gid           | gid                 | 4       | const                | 185368 | Using where                                  |
+------+--------------+---------------+--------+----------------------+---------------------+---------+----------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: show the explain results, please.  it usually contains a lot of useful information that can be used to solve these problems.

Comment: @BrentWorden, Edited my question

Comment: at first glance, i would insure the proper indices are on table1.  the whole of the where clause relies on it.  second, i would check the indices for `table` to make the inner select well behaved.

Comment: @BrentWorden, Thank you vary much for your suggestion and time. Will check like that

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `ROWS_EXAMINED` by using the Performance Schema.

Here is a link to the performance schema quick start guide. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html

This is the query I run in PHP applications, to find out what queries I need to optimize. You should be able to adapt it pretty easily.

The query finds the stats on the query that was run before this one. So in my apps, I run query after every query I run, store the results, then at the end of the PHP script I output the stats for every query I ran during the request.

```
            SELECT `EVENT_ID`, TRUNCATE(`TIMER_WAIT`/1000000000000,6) as Duration,
            `SQL_TEXT`, `DIGEST_TEXT`, `NO_INDEX_USED`, `NO_GOOD_INDEX_USED`, `ROWS_AFFECTED`, `ROWS_SENT`, `ROWS_EXAMINED` 
            FROM `performance_schema`.`events_statements_history` 
            WHERE 
            `CURRENT_SCHEMA` = '{$database}' AND `EVENT_NAME` LIKE 'statement/sql/%'
            AND `THREAD_ID` = (SELECT `THREAD_ID` FROM `performance_schema`.`threads` WHERE `performance_schema`.`threads`.`PROCESSLIST_ID` = CONNECTION_ID()) 
            ORDER BY `EVENT_ID` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

To decrease the number of rows accessed from `og_membership`, try adding an index containing the `gid`, `entity_type`, and `etid` fields.  Including `gid` and `entity_type` should make the lookup more performant and including `etid` will make the index a covering index.

After adding the index, run `EXPLAIN` again to look at the results.  Based on the new explain plan, either keep the index, remove the index, and/or add an additional index.  Keep doing this until you get results you are satisfied with.

For sure, you will want to try and eliminate any mentions of `Using temporary` or `Using filesort`.  `Using temporary` implies a temporary table is being used to make this query probably for the sheer size of your intermittent.  `Using filesort` implies ordering isn't being satisfied with an index and is being done by examining the matching rows.

An detail explanation about `EXPLAIN` can be found at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html.

Answer (score 0):

Key-Value (EAV) schema sucks.

Indexes:

```
table1: INDEX(title, created)
table1: INDEX(uid, title, created)
table: INDEX(gid, entity_type, etid)
table* -- Is `entity_id` already an index?  Can it be the PRIMARY KEY?
```

Does `nid` need to be `NULL` instead of `NOT NULL`?

If those don't do enough, try:

And turn the `IN ( SELECT ... )` into a `JOIN ( SELECT ... ) USING(hid)`

If you still need help, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`